# setOnItemClickListener solo me coge el valor del primer elemento de la lista en android

Tags: android

Hola querría que echaseis un vistazo a mi código , la lista la relleno a partir de una llamada en la base de datos donde vuelco los valores en dicha lista. lo que me quiero hacer es que cuando se haga click sobre un elemento de la lista, los datos se muestren sobre un dialogo de alerta. solo me coge el primer elemento de la lista aunque haga click sobre otros

```html
 lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                TextView tx1=adapterView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                TextView tx2=adapterView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);

                String texto1=tx1.getText().toString();
                String texto2=tx2.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), texto1+" "+texto2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La `View` que te llega como 2do parámetro es la row "clickeada" en la lista, por lo tanto debes hacer `findViewById` sobre esa para obtener los `text` de esa `row`.

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                TextView tx1=view.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                TextView tx2=view.findViewById(R.id.txt2);

                String texto1=tx1.getText().toString();
                String texto2=tx2.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), texto1+" "+texto2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

---

### Mas información:

Sobre los parámetros:

> **parent** *AdapterView*: El AdapterView donde sucedió el evento de click
>
> **view** *View*: La vista dentro de AdapterView en la que se hizo click (En tu caso la Row)
>
> **position**  *int*: La posición de la vista en el adaptador.
>
> **id** *long*: el Id de la fila del item donde se hizo click.

Comment: genial muchas gracias ya me funciona, claro es que le estaba haciendo click directamente a la lista no?

Comment: ya esta gracias de nuevo

Comment: Hola @FedericoMadoery , recuerda que se puede votar también por las preguntas, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El `ListView` te manda un parámetro `int i` que puede traducirse como una posición de la lista. Entonces lo que podrías intentar también es:

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

               Object item = list.getItemAtPosition(i); 

            }
        });
```

El código de arriba debería capturar el los datos de la lista en esa posición, y usarlo en tus TextView o en lo que corresponda.